# Running and viewing results from bash scripts

Tags: shell, shell-command

How can I run bash scripts from emacs and show the result in emacs?

Answer (score 4):

Did you try the `shell-command` command? If you don’t know what it does, run `C-h f shell-command` to see the help for it:

```
shell-command is an interactive and byte-compiled function defined in
simple.el.gz.

Signature
(shell-command COMMAND &optional OUTPUT-BUFFER ERROR-BUFFER)

Documentation
Execute string COMMAND in inferior shell; display output, if any.

With prefix argument, insert the COMMAND's output at point.

Interactively, prompt for COMMAND in the minibuffer.
```

Answer (score 2):

Type `M-x shell` and enter your command.

In addtion to `M-x shell-command`, there is also `shell-command-on-region` which will pipe the Emacs region into your command and output the results to the *Messages* buffer.

Answer (score 1):

A fun and esoteric way to see the output of a program in emacs is to use **[Eshell Redirection](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EshellRedirection)**.

1. <kbd>M-x eshell</kbd> - Start up eshell
2. <kbd>ls /usr > #<buffer *scratch*></kbd> - Redirect the output of `ls /usr` to the *scratch* buffer.
3. <kbd>C-x b *scratch*</kbd> - Switch to the *scratch* buffer to verify the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can also run bash scripts from an Org mode file using `babel`. Add something like this to your Org mode file:

```
#+begin_src shell
date
#+end_src
```

Pressing `C-c C-c` on the source block runs the script, producing the following output:

```
#+RESULTS:
: Fri Oct 28 10:14:18 AM EDT 2022
```

It can be an arbitrary script, e.g. create a `/tmp/my-script` file like this:

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "This is the output of my script"
```

then make it executable with `chmod +x /tmp/my-script` and then add the following source block to an Org mode file:

```
#+begin_src shell
/tmp/my-script
#+end_src
```

Pressing `C-c C-c` on the source block produces the following output:

```
#+RESULTS:
: This is the output of my script
```

You can read about source blocks in Org mode in the manual with `C-h i g(org)RET m Working with source code RET`.